# How to copy char pointer from device to host

Tags: cuda

I'd like to the "**text**" variable in the main to have "*some text*" in it. How do I use **cudaMemcpyFromSymbol()** to achieve this?

```
__device__ char* pointerToSomething;

__global__ void DoSomething()
{
   pointerToSomething = "some text";
}

int main()
{
   char text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can't be done with only a single call to `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol` (it will require 2 copying steps) and you can't store 9 characters of text in a variable declared as `char text;`

So with those two items mentioned, you could do it this way:

```
$ cat t1606.cu
#include <iostream>
__device__ char* pointerToSomething;
__global__ void DoSomething()
{
   pointerToSomething = "some text";
}

int main()
{
   char text[32] = {0};
   char *data;
   DoSomething<<<1,1>>>();
   cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&data, pointerToSomething, sizeof(char *));
   cudaMemcpy(text, data, 9, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   std::cout << text << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t1606 t1606.cu
t1606.cu(5): warning: conversion from a string literal to "char *" is deprecated

t1606.cu(5): warning: conversion from a string literal to "char *" is deprecated

$ cuda-memcheck ./t1606
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
some text
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

It can work the same way with `printf`:

```
$ cat t1606.cu
#include <cstdio>
__device__ char* pointerToSomething;
__global__ void DoSomething()
{
   pointerToSomething = "some text";
}

int main()
{
   char text[32] = {0};
   char *data;
   DoSomething<<<1,1>>>();
   cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&data, pointerToSomething, sizeof(char *));
   cudaMemcpy(text, data, 9, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   printf("%s\n", text);
}
$ nvcc -o t1606 t1606.cu
t1606.cu(5): warning: conversion from a string literal to "char *" is deprecated

t1606.cu(5): warning: conversion from a string literal to "char *" is deprecated

$ cuda-memcheck ./t1606
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
some text
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: thank you, it's working now, the only thing is i get "╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠" after the string when i use printf. why could this be?

Comment: I don't see any difference with `printf`.  I've updated the answer to include that example as well.  Perhaps you are not initializing your `text` array with zero like I am?  That is necessary to get a null-terminated string.  Anyway I won't be able to tell you what is wrong with code you haven't shown.

Comment: Don't forget to copy the null character `\0` at the end of the string!

Comment: The null termination is taken care of by initializing the `text` storage to zero before copying into it!